# Bison/Flex parsing issue

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am working with bison and flex and am currently have some issues.  Currently the first character is read and passed to Bison, but immediately yyerror() is thrown. It should print 1 as 'w' is an Ident defined by my Flex rules.

I cannot identify the source of the issue. I am inexperienced using Bison.

Here are my bison parsing rules:

```
    %%

   Prog : StmtSeq               {printf("13");};
   StmtSeq : Stmt StmtSeq           {printf("12");};
   StmtSeq :                        {printf("11");}; 
   Stmt : Id ':' Expr       {printf("10");}; 
   Expr : Expr '+' Term     {printf("9");}; 
   Expr : Term                  {printf("8");}; 
   Term : Term '*' Factor   {printf("7");};
   Term : Factor                {printf("6");};
   Factor   : '(' Expr ')'          {printf("5");}; 
   Factor   : '{' Expr '}'          {printf("4");}; 
   Factor   : Id                    {printf("3");}; 
   Factor   : SetLit                {printf("2");};
   Id       : Ident                 {printf("1");};

   %%
```

Here is my flex grammar:

```
    {letter} {return Ident;}
    (\{\})|(\{{letter}(\,{letter})*\}) {return SetLit;} 
    \( {return '(';}
    \) {return ')';}
    \* {return '*';}
    \+ {return '+';}
    \{ {return '{';}
    \} {return '}';}
    \: {return ':';}
    [ ]             {return;}
    \t              {return;}
    \r              {return;}
    \n              {return;}
    . {writeIndicator(getCurrentColumnNum()); writeMessage("Illegal Character in lex"); }
```

The input is a .txt file that contains:

```
  w: {f,x,a,b,c,d,e}
  x: {f,a,b,c,d,e}
  y: {}
  z: {x}
  a: {f,x,a,b,c,d,e}
  b: {}
```

Comment: The standard output is line-buffered by default when it is connected to a terminal, or fully-buffered otherwise.  Whatever is waiting in the buffer may be lost if the program terminates abnormally.  You probably want to add a newline, for example `printf("1\n");`.  You should consider also sending the output to the standard error instead of the standard output, for example `fprintf(stderr, "1\n");`.

Comment: I added the new line character and it solved that problem, but now it says the next character is illegal in YACC.

Comment: You should learn how to use bison's trace feature; it is much more informative and a lot less work than trying to debug grammars by inserting `printf` calls (which as @JohnBollinger says should be `fprintf(stderr,...)`). Some notes on how to debug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59914260/1566221)

Comment: Yacc doesn't have a "next character is illegal" message. Perhaps you are talking about the message you seem to be printing in your lex fallback rule. If so, it should tell you *which*  character is illegal (and if it doesn't, you should fix your error reporting).

Comment: Final note: if you insist on using macros like `{letter}` in your lex rules, please have the courtesy of showing their definitions. But better is not to use them. `[[:alpha:]]`, `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:alnum:]]` are built-in and do not depend on you typing the definitions correctly. (There are some other standard classes as well. See the [flex manual pattern rule summary](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html).)

Comment: My debugging process tells me that when '{' is passed to the parser yyerror is called. According to my lex, '{' shouldn't even be passed. SetLit should be passed which would be reduced to Factor. Please help. Also, I already had #define YYDEBUG 1 in my bison file prologue.

Comment: @sengineer23: (1) that's not what you report in your question. (2) it's not enough to define YYERROR, and you shouldn't do that anyway. Use the appropriate command-line flag and remember to set `yyerror` to a non-zero value. If you do have bison traces, then include them in your question. (And if you don't have them, get them and then include them.) Your debugging process might tell you all sorts of stuff but it doesn't tell me anything. You have to show what you see if you expect me to be able to help you. Please read the SO help on preparing a [mre].

Comment: And note that I don't get notified of you comment unless you @ me in the comment.

Comment: @rici I added --debug to my bison command (bison -d < "test.txt" --debug) and it did not add anything to the console when I ran the program.

Comment: @sengineer23: because you didn't set `yyerror` to a non-zero value, as I said in my comment and in the post I suggested you read, and as is well-documented in the bison manual debugging section.

Comment: Anyway, I think my answer will solve the immediate problem. But please follow the steps for you next question.

Comment: Note that your SetLit pattern does not match `{}`.  Most commonly you would want to recognize sets like this in the parser, rather than the lexer -- so have rules `Factor : '{' IdList '}'` and `IdList : Id | IdList ',' Id`, though this ends up being ambigous with `Factor: '{' Expr '}'` for a single Id in the list, so you need to decide how you want to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want lex to ignore a token, the pattern which matches that token should do nothing. `return` does not do nothing; it causes `yylex` to return. Furthermore, it is undefined behaviour because you haven't specified the value `yylex` should `return`. (Compiling with `-Wall` might have caught this problem.)

So when the scanner reads a space, it returns some unspecified value to the caller (`yyparse`). Naturally, this doesn't work as expected.

Change (for example)

```
[ ]             {return;}
```

To

```
[ ]             ;
```

Or, better, replace that sequence of redundant rules with

```
[[:space:]]+    ;
```

Comment: That did fix the immediate problem, thank you! Now I have encountered another trivial issue. I think it may be an issue with the lex. The SetLit should be returned to the parser, but instead each individual letter in the list is being returned as an IDENT @rici

Comment: @sengineer23: [The post I referred you to before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910914/syntax-error-in-compiler-made-with-flex-and-bison/59914260#59914260) has suggestions for debugging scanners. It strongly recommends doing this before you try to write your parser. That's my suggestion still. I can't do this for you even if I thought it was a good idea because, as I said earlier, you didn't share your complete lex file.

Comment: @sengineer23: About all I can say is that if you defined `{letter}` correctly and your lex file is as you say it is (with nothing odd in the prolog) then it works perfectly. So either one of those assumptions is wrong, or the problem is not in your lex definition.