# Yacc not accepting valid input

Tags: arrays, c, bison, yacc, lex

I am using Bison/Flex to create a compiler for a C-like (simplified version of C) language. I am trying to implement arrays and I am running into an issue and I can not find the source of the error. I have been stuck on this for a couple days so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Current output:

```
g[
illegal character in yacc
```

Sample Input:

```
g[10]
```

These are the two lines in the yacc that deal with the array.

```
Factor       : Arr                                              {$$ = $1;}; //doRval
Arr         : Id '[' Expr ']'                                   {$$ = getArr($1, $3);};
```

Full yac:

```
extern int yylex(); /* The next token function. */
extern char *yytext;   /* The matched token text.  */
extern int yyleng;      /* The token text length.   */
extern int yyparse();
extern int yyerror(char *);
void dumpTable();

extern SymTab *table;

%}


%union {
  long val;
  char * string;
  struct ExprRes * ExprRes;
  struct InstrSeq * InstrSeq;
  struct BExprRes * BExprRes;
  struct IdList * vL;
  struct ExprResList * eL;
}

%type <string> Id
%type <ExprRes> Factor
%type <ExprRes> Arr
%type <ExprRes> Term
%type <ExprRes> Expr
%type <InstrSeq> StmtSeq
%type <InstrSeq> Stmt
%type <vL> vList
%type <eL> eList

%token Ident        
%token ArrDec
%token IntLit   
%token Int
%token Write
%token IF
%token WHILE
%token FOR
%token ELSE
%token EQ   
%token AND
%token OR
%token LTE
%token GTE
%token NEQ
%token READ
%token PrintLine
%token PrintSpaces

%%

Prog            :   Declarations StmtSeq                        {Finish($2); } ;
Declarations    :   Dec Declarations                            { };
Declarations    :                                               { };
Dec             : ArrDec {arrDec(yytext);}             {};
Dec         :   Int Ident {enterName(table, yytext); }';'       {};
StmtSeq         :   Stmt StmtSeq                                {$$ = AppendSeq($1, $2); } ;
StmtSeq     :                                                   {$$ = NULL;} ;
Stmt            : Write Expr ';'                                {$$ = doPrint($2); };
Stmt            : Id '=' Expr ';'                               {$$ = doAssign($1, $3);} ;
//Stmt          : Arr '=' Expr ';'                              {$$ = doArrAssign($1, $3);} ;
Stmt            : FOR '(' Stmt Expr ';' Stmt ')' '{' StmtSeq '}'                {$$ = doFor($3, $4, $6, $9);};
Stmt            : WHILE '(' Expr ')' '{' StmtSeq '}'                {$$ = doWhile($3, $6);};
Stmt            : IF '(' Expr ')' '{' StmtSeq '}'               {$$ = doIf($3, $6);};
Stmt            : IF '(' Expr ')' '{' StmtSeq '}' ELSE '{'  StmtSeq '}'             {$$ = doIfElse($3, $6, $10);};
Stmt            : Write '(' eList ')' ';'                       {$$ = doPrintExpList($3);};
Stmt            : PrintLine '(' Expr ')' ';'                    {$$ = doPrintLine($3);};
Stmt            : PrintSpaces '(' Expr ')' ';'                    {$$ = doPrintSpaces($3);};
Stmt            : READ '(' vList ')' ';'                        {$$ = doRead($3);};
eList           : Expr                                          {$$ = addExpr($1, NULL);};
eList           : Expr ',' eList                                {$$ = addExpr($1, $3);};
eList           :                                               {$$ = NULL;};
vList           : Id                                            {$$ = addId($1, NULL);};
vList           : Id ',' vList                                  {$$ = addId($1, $3);};
vList           :                                               {$$ = NULL;};
Expr        :   Expr EQ Expr                                    {$$ = doEQ($1, $3);};
Expr            :   Expr NEQ Term                               {$$ = doNEQ($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Expr LTE Term                               {$$ = doLTE($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Expr GTE Term                               {$$ = doGTE($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Expr '<' Term                               {$$ = doLess($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Expr '>' Term                               {$$ = doGreater($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Expr '^' Term                               {$$ = doExp($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Expr OR Term                                {$$ = doOr($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Expr '-' Term                               {$$ = doSub($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Expr '+' Term                               {$$ = doAdd($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Term                                        {$$ = $1; } ;
Term        :   Term AND Factor                                 {$$ = doAnd($1, $3); } ;
Term        :   Term '%' Factor                                 {$$ = doRemainder($1, $3);} ;
Term        :   Term '/' Factor                                 {$$ = doDiv($1, $3); } ;
Term        :   Term '*' Factor                                 {$$ = doMult($1, $3); } ;
Term        :   Factor                                          {$$ = $1;};
Factor      : '!' Factor                                        {$$ = doNot($2);};
Factor      : '-' Factor                                        {$$ = doUnary($2);};
Factor      : '(' Expr ')'                                      {$$ = $2};
Factor       : Arr                                              {$$ = $1;}; //doRval
Arr         : Id '[' Expr ']'                                   {$$ = getArr($1, $3);};
Factor      :   IntLit                                          {$$ = doIntLit(yytext); };
Factor      :   Id                                              {$$ = doRval(yytext); };
Id          :   Ident                                           {$$ = strdup(yytext);};
 
%%

int yyerror(char *s)  {
  writeIndicator(getCurrentColumnNum());
  writeMessage("illegal character in yacc");
  return 1;
}
```

here is my lex:

```
letter [A-Za-z]
digit [0-9]

%%
if {return IF; }
else {return ELSE;}
while {return WHILE;}
for {return FOR;}
int {return Int;}
print {return Write;}
read {return READ;}
printlines {return PrintLine;}
printspaces {return PrintSpaces;};
"int "{letter}({letter}|{digit})*\[{digit}+\]\; {return ArrDec;}
{letter}({letter}|{digit})* {return Ident;}
\, {return ',';}
{digit}{digit}* {return IntLit; }
\[ {return '[';}
\] {return ']';}
\=\= {return EQ; }
\!\= {return NEQ; }
\= {return '='; }
\+ {return '+'; }
\^ {return '^'; }
\- {return '-'; }
\< {return '<'; }
\> {return '>'; }
\<\= {return LTE; }
\>\= {return GTE; }
\! {return '!'; }
&& {return AND;}
\|\| {return OR;}
\* {return '*'; }
\; {return ';'; }
\{ {return '{'; }
\} {return '}'; }
\( { return '('; }
\) { return ')'; }
\% { return '%'; }
\/ { return '/'; }
[ ] {}
\t {}
\r {}
\n {}
. {writeIndicator(getCurrentColumnNum()); writeMessage("Illegal Character in lex"); }
%%
```

Comment: In your `yyerror` function, why don't you print the string that was provided as an argument? It might contain a hint about the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how do I do that. I tried printing yytext but that did not work.

Comment: The function `yyerror` have an argument `s`. Print it using your error-reporting function (like e.g. `writeMessage(s);`?)

Comment: Also, your YACC program probably have some flags to display debug or state information, and possibly add debuging code to the generated parser.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am already using bison -d bb.y --debug

Comment: Also, try to *simplify* your parser. Start at the most simple possible, like `Prog: Id; Id: Ident;`. Test and fix until it works. Then add a new single and simple rule, test until it works. And so on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have been doing that, have already implemented everything else successfully.

Comment: Do you really have a `^` in the output of `s`? That really shouldn't be there. Please [edit] your question to show both the full and complete output, copy-pasted as text without any modifications (as well as update the code to the one writing that output). And if possible try to simplify the grammar to only the few minimal rules for an expression such as `g[10]`.

Comment: By the way (and unrelated to your problem), shouldn't the `yyerror` function be declared as returning `void`? That's what I remember, and also what [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Reporting-Function.html) say.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The documentation says (taken from your link): "Bison-generated code always ignores the returned value, so **yyerror can return any type**, including void."

Comment: @sengineer23: You use `--debug` as a command-line flag, but you don't enable debugging. As I told you a [few weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062630/bison-flex-parsing-issue#comment118542941_67062630). In fact, [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062630/bison-flex-parsing-issue#comment118543227_67062630). Or [three times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910914/syntax-error-in-compiler-made-with-flex-and-bison/59914260#59914260) if you include this answer with sample code. And it's all still true: Enable debugging and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Oh, and that's not your "full yacc". It doesn't start with `{%`; it's missing necessary includes, and it uses functions whose definitions you don't show.

Comment: Additionally, you should take a look at the state machine output (`-v` command-line option) and fix the shift-reduce conflicts which you chose not to mention in your question. The less you tell us, the more difficult it is for us to help you.

Comment: The first problem is your message. `yyerror()` is called on syntax errors. Syntax errors are not 'illegal characters'. You should have printed the string supplied as an argument to `yyerror()`, instead of making up your own error message, and the current content of `yytext`,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in that grammar allows a statement to start with a subscripted array, since you don't allow statements to be expressions, and the production which would have allowed array assignment has been commented out.

```
//Stmt          : Arr '=' Expr ';'     {$$ = doArrAssign($1, $3);} ;
```

So bison reports a syntax error, which your `yyerror` implementation ignores, preferring to print its own misleading error message. Unless you know what you're doing, `yyerror` should always print the argument it's given. (See any number of examples of simple `yyerror` implementations throughout the bison manual.)

Comment: Now I am having issues with my adding expressions. For example, c = 1 + 1; works fine, but anytime there is an Ident involved (i.e. c = c + 1;) something weird happens. The '+' will be recognized as an Ident somehow and messes everything up. Do you know what could be causing this? I think it may be a weird conflict because c is an Id which can be an Expr, so the assignment rule thinks its done after it finds the 'c'?

Comment: @sengineer23: what do you see in the bison trace? (If you need help interpreting it, please create a new question and paste the trace into it.)

Comment: It is not giving me any errors. This is my command (bison -d ExprEval.y --debug). It is just recognizing the '+' as an Id somehow.

Comment: ExprEval.y: conflicts: 11 shift/reduce

Comment: @sengineer23: I'm not going to try again to explain to you how to get a trace. If you want to debug your grammar, then you need to learn how to 
get traces and then you need to learn how to read them. It's not difficult. It's in my comments above.

Comment: And you should fix those conflicts.